# Optimization with Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization

A common way to write the objective function in matlab (including the gradient vector) is the following:

```
[L,G] = objfun(x)
```

where `L` is the value of objective function, `G` is the gradient vector and `x` is a vector of coefficients which I want to optimize.

However, when I include another input (i.e  `[L,G]=objfun(x,M)`, where `M` is a matrix) or when I call another function in the function `objfun`, the code is not running.

How can I include any inputs and call any functions in the `objfun` by keeping this format of optimization?

Note that I call the optimization as follows:

```
[x ,fval] = fminunc(@objfun,x,options)
```

where

```
options = optimoptions(@fminunc,'Algorithm','quasinewton',...
                      'Display','iter','Gradobj','on','TolFun',10^-8)
```

Comment: Hey, could you add a minimal working/not working example, i.e. how would you call the optimizer? Which optimizer? Please add that information to your question via "edit".

Comment: Mr Marcus Muller, thanks for the reply. I have already added the information that you have suggested

Comment: thanks you! ah, now things are much easier to answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an mathworks help article on [passing extra parameters](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/passing-extra-parameters.html) to the objective function:

You can use the `@(...)` operator to generate an anonymous function handle to your function that will only depend on a single parameter.

```
a = 4; b = 2.1; c = 4;
f = @(x)objfun(x,a,b,c)
```

From the original page (where your `objfun` is `parameterfun`):

> **Note:**   The parameters passed in the anonymous function are those that exist at the time the anonymous function is created. Consider the
>   example
>
> ```
> a = 4; b = 2.1; c = 4;
> f = @(x)parameterfun(x,a,b,c)
> ```
>
> Suppose you subsequently change, a to 3 and run
>
> ```
> [x,fval] = fminunc(f,x0)
> ```
>
> You get the same answer as before, since parameterfun uses a = 4, the
>   value when f was created.
>
> To change the parameters that are passed to the function, renew the
>   anonymous function by reentering it:
>
> ```
> a = 3;
> f = @(x)parameterfun(x,a,b,c)
> ```

Comment: Thanks Mr Muller! I have made significant progress after reading your answer!

Comment: In that case: I'd love to see my solution being accepted as soon as you find your problem solved :)

Comment: @ZenonTaoushianis Welcome to functional programming.